# Any way to insert fields only if they don't already exist in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, json, database, mongodb, backend

I've tried some solutions i've found but im not getting how this is supposed to work (im new to mongo). i have a document that looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63ef95daf324e5a26354eb61"
  },
  "idCarga": "6182944",
  "12121212121212": {
    "info1": "hello",
    "info2": "goodbye"
  },
  "13131313131313": {
    "info1": "hello",
    "info2": "goodbye"
  }
}
```

My goal is to:

1. If i try to update the document with a new product ID field (like 15151515151515), it gets inserted as a new field.
2. If i try to update the document with an already existing prod ID (like 13131313131313), nothing happens (dont insert or update anything).

I got some results with the `$exists` operator paired with `upsert` option. But i have to insert so many product IDs it seems like an unviable option. Is there any way to do this with only one document per "idCarga"? Or do i have to separate this into 2 collections? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ray yes i do. The problem is that i'm not inserting a new document, only new fields, so setOnInsert will only add the product ID fields when the document is created. When i try to update the document with new fields, those new fields dont get inserted, cause they are only inserted on update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do a `$set` with `$ifNull`

```js
db.collection.update({
  <your criteria>
},[
  {
    $set: {
      "<your id>": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$<your id>",
          {
            <your new sub doc>
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground for new id case](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_JCHy_RpCkU)

[Mongo Playground for existing id case](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7iZ9OrXHKds)

Comment: I dont know if i'm doing this correctly (im using mongosh to input these commands), but the "$ifNull" just gets inserted as a field (with or without the double quotes).

Comment: @FernandoPinedo Can you update your question with your latest attempts?

Comment: Oh, it seems i forgot the `[]` after the comma of the criteria. IT WORKS, thanks!

Comment: care to explain the syntax behind the `[]` after the criteria object? Or point to a reference somewhere i can learn from this? I did somewhat understand the $ifNull operator, but im not so sure about the `[]` or `$<your id>` parts. Thanks again for the answer!!

Comment: @FernandoPinedo it is [update with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/). It is a relatively new feature that allow you to use some subset of aggregation in an update operation.